# Cordova windows uwp app cookies get cleared after restarting the application

Tags: cordova, cordova-windows

I'm building a cordova windows uwp app, and want to do SAML authentication. I am using the cordova-inAppBrowser plugin to be able to call the authentication url. I am receiving the cookies, after the authentication, but when I'm closing the app, and restarting again, the cookies are not there anymore - this means, that I need to authenticate again.

I checked if I am receiving the cookies, and I can confirm, that I am receiving the cookies. I have also tried setting the cookies directly on the app from the inAppBrowser, but after restarting the application, I am not able to see the cookie anymore.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("urlforSAMLAuthentication", "_blank", "location=yes");

    const doc = document;

    ref.addEventListener("loaderror", function () {
        ref.executeScript(
            { code: "document.cookie" },
            (values) => {
                                // try setting the cookie directly on the document
                doc.cookie = values[0]
            }
        );
    });
```

I expect after closing the application and restarting the application, the cookie to be still available when I'm typing in the console document.cookie. But this is not the case

Comment: I don't think you can use cookies in app, i think you have to use the localStorage, also you should get used to using localStorage over cookies because of the stupid rules being applied to cookies of late.

Comment: @MartinBarker , I cannot use only localStorage as I also have some http-only cookies. And these cookies are not readable by calling `document.cookie`. In my Example I just wanted to point out that my cookies are getting deleted.